# Server client socket connection android

Tags: android, serversocket

I have implemented server client socket connection in android to send and receive string data between to android phones. I just wants to know whether this method is reliable, if my application closed will this connection remains or terminated. And is this connection closes after sometime ???

Answer (score 4):

If your application closed then connection will also get terminated. I think you need to use services in android for your application.

Comment: I don't suppose the connection is terminated immediately.

Comment: No, I mean after any one server or client get closed then again we need to established connection,because it will not resume from where we have left transmission.